# HTML input checkbox get value from mysql via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

How do I set the checkbox `nd` is checked if the value in `mysql` is `1`?

```
<?php
    $select_PO=mysql_query("SELECT pono, nd, r, adj, no, am, ct, poyes, poyesp, pon FROM tb_po WHERE pono = '". $id ."' AND postatus !='Approved' AND pono NOT IN (SELECT pono FROM tb_postatus)", $conn);
    $count=mysql_num_rows($select_PO);

    if ($count == 1) {
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($select_PO);
        if ($row['nd'] = 1) {
            $nd="checked";
        }
        if ($row['r'] = 1) {
            $nd="checked";
        }
        mysql_close($conn);
?>
<input type="checkbox" id="nd" name="nd" checked="<?php echo $nd ?> "/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out,

```
<?php
    $select_PO=mysql_query("SELECT pono, nd, r, adj, no, am, ct, poyes, poyesp, pon FROM tb_po WHERE pono = '". $id ."' AND postatus !='Approved' AND pono NOT IN (SELECT pono FROM tb_postatus)", $conn);
    $count=mysql_num_rows($select_PO);

    if ($count == 1) {
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($select_PO);
        if ($row['nd'] = 1) {
            $nd="checked";
        }
        if ($row['r'] = 1) {
            $nd="checked";
        }
        mysql_close($conn);
?>
<input type="checkbox" id="nd" name="nd" <?php echo $nd ?> />
```

Comment: very sorry my mistake, the nd value in mysql is string "1" or "0", so i want to make the checkbox "nd" checked if the value is 1 and uncheck for value 0

Comment: the problem has been fixed, thanks everyone. changed the following if ((int)$row['nd']==1) { $nd="checked"; } else { $nd="";} with <input type="checkbox" id="nd" name="nd" <?php echo $nd ?> />

Answer (score 0):

The attribute "checked" on an HTML checkbox input is a boolean value. That means it implies the checkbox is checked purely by existence.

```
<input type="checkbox" />                     <!-- Not checked -->
<input type="checkbox" checked />             <!-- checked -->
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />   <!-- checked -->
```

It does not matter what the value of the checked attribute is, or if it even has one. The presence of the attribute means the checkbox is checked.